# Flowstrates and R: extracting and reshaping data in required format

Tags: r, sqlite, dataframe

I'm working on trying to transform a large dataset into the required formats for analyzing within the [flowstrates](http://code.google.com/p/jflowmap/wiki/Flowstrates) package.

What I currently have is a large file (600k trips) with origin and destination points.

Format is sort of like this:

```
tripID   Month start_pt   end_pt
1        June   1           3
2        June   1           3
3        July   1           5
4        July   1           7
5        July   1           7
```

What I need to be able to generate is a file that has trip counts by unit time (let's say months) in a format like this:

```
start_pt   end_pt  June July August ... December
1          3       2    0    5          9
1          5       0    1    4          4
1          7       0    2    0          0
```

It's easy enough to pre-segment the data by month and then generate counts for each origin-destination pair, but then putting it all back together causes all sorts of problems since each of the pre-segmented chunks of data have very different sizes. So it seems that I'd need to do this for the entire dataset at once.

Are there any packages for doing this type of processing? Would it be easier to do this in something like SQL or SQLite?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `reshape2` package to do this fairly easily.

If your data is `dat`,

```
library("reshape2")
dcast(dat, start_pt+end_pt~Month, value.var="tripID", fun.aggregate=length)
```

This gives a single entry for each `start_pt`/`end_pt`/`Month` combination, the value of which is how many cases had that combination (the length of `tripID` for that set).

Comment: @scuerda: Don't forget to press the "Answer" button if it worked.